# How to declare values in .yaml file Environment Variables and Call it in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, robotframework

I have a config.yaml file which is used to store all Database and API key credentials while developing for Robot Framework.

I have to place the config.yaml in Jenkins workspace and pass the path to command line to override.

```
robot --variablefile <jenkins workspace path>/config.yaml test1.robot
```

Below is the config.yaml file:

```
db_mysql:
    DB_USER: '**********'
    DB_HOST: '**********'
    DB_PWD: '***********'
    DB_NAME: '**********'
    DB_PORT: '**********'

db2_mysql:
    DB2_USER: '*********'
    DB2_HOST: '**********'
    DB2_PWD: '*************'
    DB2_NAME: '**************'
    DB2_PORT: '*************'

api_key:
    APIkey: '****************'

base_url:
    BASE_URL: '***************'
```

How can I declare all the values as Environment Variables and associate it with Jenkins environment Variables?

Also, I have three environments:

1. Local
2. Staging and
3. Production

How to provide or pass if its local to pick local credentials respectively for Staging and Production from Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function "readYaml" to assign all file to variable

```
def datas = readYaml text: """
something: 'my datas'
size: 3
isEmpty: false
"""
        assert datas.something == 'my datas'
        assert datas.size == 3
        assert datas.isEmpty == false
```

(see [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text))

Regards